# VPN client for use with the AirVPN VPN service

Tags: vpn

I have been using the AirVPN service for a while now but their client is abysmal and I fear continuing to use it, will comprise my privacy.

I chose AirVPN after a few people I trust recommended it but they did warn about their client.

I am plagued by constant connection disconnection loops. I have downgraded to an older version of the client, still no luck.

Can you recommend me a client that supports AirVPN? Something that is

- stable and reliable
- Automation friendly through the command line
- Extensive configuration options

That last one is not must but would be great to have.

I am on windows 11

Any help would be greatly appreciated!